# Bring "Back to top" icon to the top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried to bring the "back to top" icon to the top but it didn't work. the table frame will cover the icon when the screen is smaller. How can I fix this?

Website: http://www.seymourrealestate.ca/

CSS program for this animated back to top icon

```
.back-to-top {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 2em;
        right: 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.85);
        font: 1.0em/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 1.0em;
        display: none;


    }

    .back-to-top:hover {    
        background-color: rgba(135, 135, 135, 0.50);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
z-index: x;
```

and see if that solves your problem. That will bring the element to the top.

EDIT:

Where X stands for a number, eg 1, 2, 1999, etc.

I just tested adding the property on my browser, it works. Add a z-index property on css.

Comment: He can ADD a number, not the x. I should've explained myself better. Will edit the answer.

Comment: Are you sure? Add to the link itself the z-index property. z-index: 5;